# Trying to learn the BASH Shell source code,but stuck with environment variables loading

Tags: bash

I was curious about how the famous Bourne shell is written.So I started digging into the source code.I understand that,One of the initial things which bash does is it loads the ~/.bash_profile file for the user env.
My question is how it loads the environment variables in the current shell.

1. Does it fork and execute it?
2. Does it read the bash_profile file and does putenv(),one for each
   variable?

In the source code `bash-2.0/shell.c`, I found a function call like,

`maybe_execute_file ("~/.bash_profile", 1);`

Even after digging further I was unable to get the exact logic as of how the values are pushed in environment.

Comment: Fork and execute obviously wouldn't work, as the variables and state changes wouldn't get back to the parent process.

Comment: Also, `.bash_profile` isn't specific to environment variables -- it's just invoked as any other source code, much the same as how running `source somefile` executes code from same, whether `somefile` is setting environment variables or doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Neither - it executes it without forking (just like the `.` or `source` built in command).  If it forked first then environment variable changes in the subshell wouldn't be visible in the original parent.

Comment: Hi Ian,Thx for your reply.I understand that forking is not an option here.Also, . /.bash_profile is how shell executes the script without creating a sub shell.I want to understand how its done via a C program.If u happen to see the code shell.c,theres no mention of a . or source anywhere.If at any point I want to run the bash_profile file then wont it be possible via a c program  as system and exec utilities create a sub shell?Is there a other way.....Just curious.Thanks.

Comment: @VijayKarode I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) - what are you actually trying to achieve here?  Are you asking how you can read the `bash_profile` and apply the settings in there to the environment of your own (non-shell) C program?

Comment: Hi Ian,I want to execute bash_profile from a c program and set up the environment of the current process.Hence thought of going through the source code of bash to get an idea how bash does it for all profile files.Sorry for my naive question.I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: @VijayKarode Far simpler would be to run your C program via a shell, e.g. `bash -l -c 'exec /path/to/your/cprogram'`.  As [mentioned in the question comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612154/trying-to-learn-the-bash-shell-source-code-but-stuck-with-environment-variables/28612893?noredirect=1#comment45529325_28612154) bash_profile can contain much more than just environment variable settings, you need the full shell command parser to process it.